# Read from .txt file so that the program uses variables and strings from the .txt file to update

Tags: java

I've written a functioning code below and I want to simply change my menu setting from within the program to outside. I've been asked to get the sodaMachine contents from a .txt file from outside the program where the program will take from the .txt file and will display "Take your drink (1.)".

My question is what do I add to get a program that accurate takes int's, and string from a .txt file on command. So if I input "1.)" the program extracts "coca-cola" and its price (an int) "150".

```
  import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CST1201 {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int coinTotal = 0;
        int coinTotal2 = 0; 
        int coinTotal3 = 0;
        int runAgain = 1;

        while(runAgain == 1)
            {
            while (coinTotal < 100){
                System.out.println("Please insert a coin ");
                coinTotal2 = input.nextInt();
                if (coinTotal2 != 25 && coinTotal2 != 5 && coinTotal2 != 10)
                {
                    coinTotal2 = 0;
                    while (coinTotal2 != 25 && coinTotal2 != 5 && coinTotal2 != 10)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Please insert a coin(5,10,25)");
                        coinTotal2 = input.nextInt();
                        if (coinTotal2 != 25 && coinTotal2 != 5 && coinTotal2 != 10)
                        {
                            coinTotal2 = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            coinTotal = coinTotal + coinTotal2;
                            coinTotal3 = coinTotal + coinTotal2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    coinTotal = coinTotal + coinTotal2;
                }
                System.out.println("Total: " + coinTotal);
            }
            int choice = 0;
            System.out.println("What would you like? \n1.Coca-Cola \n2.Pepsi \n3.Orange Soda \n4.Grape Soda \n5.Mountain Dew \n6.Water");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice ==1) {
                System.out.println("Please take your Coca-Cola");
            } else {
                if(choice == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Please take your pepsi");
                } else {
                    if (choice == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Please take your Orange Soda");
                    } else {
                        if (choice == 4) {
                            System.out.println("Please take your Grape Soda");
                        } else {
                            if (choice == 5) {
                                System.out.println("Please take your Mountain Dew");
                            } else {
                                if (choice == 6) {
                                    System.out.println("Please take your water");
                                }
                               }
                              }
                             }
                            }
                           }
            int change;
            if (coinTotal > 100){
                change = coinTotal - 100;
                System.out.println("Please take your change: " + change);
            }
                System.out.println("Would you like to buy another drink?");
                runAgain = input.nextInt();
                if (runAgain == 1)
                {
                   coinTotal = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    runAgain = 0;
                    System.out.println("Thank you");
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to take as input coinTotal, coinTotal2, coinTotal3, choice, and runagain from a .txt file and run your program multiple times for the given inputs?

If that is the case, you can just put your whole method into a function with the above parameters, and give parameters in a loop through your .txt input file.
You can use File, and Scanner to read the contents from the file depending on how its arranged in the file.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("FileName")); // this gets you your file
```

You can access elements of file as a 1 word string, using scan.next() and then parse it to your appropriate need, and then pass it on to your function.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you. I just figured how to do it, I am now working on how do I update the .txt file.